# Fetching rows with Snowflake JDBC while the query is running in the server

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a complex query that runs a long time (e.g 30 minutes) in Snowflake when I run it in the Snowflake console. I am making the same query from a JVM application using JDBC driver. What appears to happen is this:

1. Snowflake processes the query from start to finish, taking 30 minutes.
2. JVM application receives the rows. The first receive happens 30 minutes after the query started.

What I'd like to happen is that Snowflake starts to send rows to my application while it is still executing the query, as soon as data is ready. This way my application could start processing the rows in the first 30 minutes.

Is this possible with Snowflake and JDBC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would request to check the Snowflake warehouse size and do the tuning. It's not worth waiting for 30 mins when by resizing of the warehouse, the query time can be reduced one fourth or less than that.  By doing any of the below, your cost will be almost the same or low. The query execution time will be reduced linearly as you increase the warehouse size. Refer the [link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-considerations.html)

1. Scale up by resizing a warehouse.
2. Scale out by adding clusters to a warehouse (requires Snowflake
   Enterprise Edition or higher).

Now coming to JDBC, I believe it behaves the same way as  for other databases as well